# How do I convert a string to an int in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

how do I convert a string to int in JS, while properly handling error cases?

I want NaN returned when the argument is not really an integer quanityt:

- blank string should return NaN (not 0)
- mixed strings (e.g. "3b") should return NaN (not 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function cNum(param) {
  return param === "" ? NaN : Number(param)
}

cNum(""); //returns NaN
cNum("3b"); //returns NaN
cNum("4.5"); //returns 4.5
```

Comment: you may also check null as it will be treated as 0.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp

Comment: I think, based on other SO Q&A, that parseInt will return "3" when given "3b" and "0" when given "".

Comment: Don't link to w3schools please. It's widely regarded as a poor and inaccurate reference.

Comment: Really? I'll admit I don't do much web development, but I've never run across anything inaccurate there. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
function stringToInt(str) {
  var num = parseInt(str);
  if (num == str)
    return num;
  return NaN;
}
```

Examples

```
stringToInt("")
NaN

stringToInt("3")
3

stringToInt("3x")
Nan
```

Comment: Simple, easy... I like it! Nothing built in though, huh?

Answer (score 0):

```
var intval = /^\d+$/.test( strval ) ? parseInt( strval ) : NaN;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need much-
if s is a string:

**s%1** will return 0 if s is an integer.

It will return a non-zero number if s is a non-integer number,

and NaN if s is not a number at all.

```
function isInt(s){
    return (s%1===0)? Number(s):NaN;
}
```

But although the number returned is an integer, to javascript it is still just a number.